# How can I access base class from List(of derived classes) using iteration?

Tags: vb.net

I collected different derived class instances using a List(Of Interface).
And naturally I only can access the Interfaced methods using iteration.

```
Public Class Base
  Public Sub Work_inBase()
  End Sub
End Class
'--------------------------
Public Interface MyIFC
  Sub Work()
End Interface
'--------------------------
Public Class Child1
  Inherits Base
  Implements MyIFC

  Public Sub Work() Implements MyIFC.Work
  End Sub
End Class
'--------------------------
Public Class Child2
  Inherits Base
  Implements MyIFC

  Public Sub Work() Implements MyIFC.Work
  End Sub
End Class
'--------------------------
Public Sub MainProgram()
  Dim C1 As New Child1()
  Dim C2 As New Child2()
  Dim MyList As New List(Of MyIFC)

  MyList.Add( C1 )
  MyList.Add( C2 )

  MyList(0).Work() >>> OK because it was interfaced
  MyList(0).Work_inBase() >>> does not work, cannot access to base
End Sub
```

Is there any other way to access to base class methods or members (which will be very large)??? Maybe different class design is required???

Thank you (vb is prefered, but I can read c# code equally too)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously there is no way to know that an arbitrary `List(Of MyIFC)` actually contains members that are or do inherit type `Base`, so there's no reason that there should be any standard functionality that would give you items of that type.  If you know for a fact that the items will be that type though, you can simply cast as that type when they come out, e.g.

```
DirectCast(MyList(0), Base).Work_inBase()
```

Of course, once you have a reference of type `Base` then you can't access members of `MyIFC` because `Base` doesn't implement that interface.  Your example is very contrived so there's no way for us to know whether there's a better design possible in your specific case.

Comment: I find it useful to test the type before casting...e.g. If TypeOf(MyList(0)) Is Base